# Is possible to pas string instead multiple parameters

Tags: c

I was wondering is there a way to do something like replacing command with string in c,

for example
replacing

```
foo()
{
  if( strcmp( (i->name, j->name)  > 0)
    //do something
}
```

with something like

```
foo(char *command)
{
   if( strcmp(arg) > 0)
     //do something
}
```

where

```
arg = " i->name, j->name ";
```

so that i could easily replace parameters of compering if i want use for example

```
arg = " i->surname, j->surname ";
```

i guess some like sending queries to sql object method?

Comment: No, that’s not possible. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: How about `void foo(const char* lhs, const char* rhs)`? To be called with `foo(i->name, j->name)` and `foo(i->surname, j->surname)`.

Comment: `int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2);` -> strcmp requires two pointers as parameters so you can't pass a string containing names of some the variables.

Comment: Think about it this way, there are no names in the program when it is running in memory. `i->name` is just a convenience for you. Once the program is compiled, that's just an address.

Comment: It might be possible by using a modifiable offset from the start of the structure.

Comment: @bace1000. Still wouldn't give you two arguments from one.

Comment: @Ryan Yeah I thought It wasnt possible, I  guess I wanted to reuse existing code without adding additional lines, sending command as string for function parameter. I cant be done because code is compiled and linked to machine code so it cant be dynamically changed.

Comment: @Stips: What do you want to reuse, though? There are usually ways to make this work – sometimes elegant ones.

Answer (score 2):

You can use #define directive to do that,

```
#define arg  i->name, j->name
```

but I would highly not recommend you to do that.

Comment: Technically, that would work. Very important disclaimer :)

Comment: I know that I could do that but I wouldnt be able to change arg what was my goal . Could you explain me why that is not recommended

Comment: The reason why it is not recommended is because if someone else would read your code. For him it would not make sense. He would not know where the variable come from, what value does it have or even type. 
Also it could be problem if you use something that has arg in it. For example main( args .... 
the preprocessor would just replace arg for i->name, j->name so after preprocessor it would be
main ( i->name, j->names
which is definitly what you intended.

Answer (score 0):

Code would need to parse the command string for the 4 parts: `i,j,name,surname`.

Then map those to objects and members

```
// sample code lacking error checking
void foo(char *command) {
  char *object1name = strtok(command, ",->");
  object *object1   = find_object_by_name(object1name);
  char *member1name = strtok(NULL, ",->");
  int offset1       = find_offset_by_name(member1name);

  char *object2name = strtok(NULL, ",->");
  object *object2   = find_object_by_name(object2name);
  char *member2name = strtok(NULL, ",->");
  int offset2       = find_offset_by_name(member2name);

  if (strcmp((char*)object1 + offset1, (char*)object2 + offset2) > 0)
    // do something
  }
}
```